# Using measuring tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, measurements

This is probably a very simple question - but opening up ArcGIS, the measure tool is unhighlighted, how do I make it so it is visible? Am I missing turning on an extension or something?

Answer (score 14):

The measure tool does not need any extension. However, the coordinate system of the data frame needs to be defined before you can use it. right-click on the data frame to set its properties.

[image]